# Django Timed Events

Tags: python, django, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule events to happen for my users. Is there an efficient way to do this in Python/Django easily? I'd prefer not to poll a priority queue.

Thanks!

Edit: I want to clarify that this job is run per user, for potentially hundreds or thousands of users.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Comment: Your OS has an "at" command which does exactly this.  Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

[Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at: http://celeryproject.org/

From the website:

> "Celery is already used in production to process millions of tasks a day."

Answer (score 0):

How about [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/)?

Comment: Not quite what I want. I want an event to trigger after x amount of time has elapsed and preferably it should scale to thousands of users without locking up the machine.