# Call a method at a specific time for Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, datetime, methods, call

In my Django web app, an event's status changes from 'upcoming' to 'completed' at a certain date/time. However, I want to update the database as soon as the event object's date/time has passed. Any ideas how I would code this?

My only idea so far is to have a thread constantly running that that checks to see if the event object's date/time as passed. However, this would be a really garbage way of doing things because there are potentially hundreds of event objects I would have to do this for.

Thanks for your help,

Chris

Comment: I did not really understand the question but if there is an event status, can't you just add an event listener?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job) - the accepted answer for this question is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [django-chronograph](http://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph/src) app is one way to schedule jobs -- it relies on a cron job to automate scheduled running of django commands.