# Regular, timed editing of a text file in Django

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, text-files

Every time a certain table is saved/created in my application I want a text file on the server to be updated in tandem. I've been thinking that this could be either done each time the model's save() method is called, or perhaps just achieved as a regular job every hour, for example.

I can't see a standard Django-y way of actually implementing this, does anyone have a suggestion, or perhaps a better idea?

Thanks very much

Comment: I would recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Comment: by table saved do you mean insert/update record record? have you looked into django's provided [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) functionality, have you considered your databases logging functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) to write the model changes in your file.

Comment: This is exactly what signals are for.

Comment: This was spot on, thank you. To anyone else who is thinking of something similar I can highly recommend this. Really easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for revision support for your models you could always use django-reversion

https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

This will keep track of all model changes.

If you want it to run every hour instead of on change, I recommend using django-celery to set up a task

https://github.com/ask/django-celery