# Maximally simple django timed/scheduled tasks (e.g.: reminders)?

Tags: python, django

Question is relevant to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/);

the difference is, I'd prefer something with possibly more precision and low load (per-minute cron job isn't preferable for those) and with minimal overhead (i.e. installing celery with rabbitmq seems like a big overkill).

An example task for such is personal reminders server (with reminders that could be edited over web and sent out through e-mail or XMPP).

I'm probably looking for something more like node.js's setTimeout but for django (and though I might prefer to implement reminders in node.js anyway, it's still a possibly interesting question).

For example, it's possible to start new threads in django app (with functions consisting of sleep() and send()); in what ways this can be bad?

Comment: I wonder whether your my clone (or vice versa) that's working on exactly the same project I am. If so, we may not survive if we ever meet. The universe seems too small for us.

Comment: You don't have to use RabbitMQ with Celery: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html (there is also Amazon SQS which is not on this list, but that would probably come with more latency than cron's one minute precision ;)

Comment: @MK_Dev, I'm actually not yet working on any such project, just planning to maybe-get-to-it.  Though if you're doing something similar or relevant, it might be interesting to join in a bit..

Comment: @asksol yes, I've noticed that; but how exactly would timed messages work in those cases (e.g. with django db as broker)?  (though I don't really know how exactly they work with rabbitmq either).

Comment: @HoverHell scheduled/timed tasks are not implemented in the broker, they are implemented by the worker (and celerybeat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using threads for this solution are the typical problems with Python threads that always drive people towards multi-process solutions instead. The problem is compounded here by the fact your thread isn't driven by the normal request-response cycle. This is summarized nicely by Malcolm Tredinnick [here](http://iraniweb.com/blog/?p=95):

> Have to disagree. Threads are not a good solution to this problem. The
>   issue is process management. As written, your threads will never be
>   rejoined. Webserver processes have a lifecycle uncontrollable by you
>   (the MaxRequestsPerChild Apache parameter and similar things in other
>   servers) and you are messing with that by using threads.
>
> If you need a process with a lifecycle that is not matched by the
>   request-response path — something long running and independent of the
>   response — a completely separate process is definitely the right model
>   to use. Using a thread is tying it to the response lifecycle, which
>   wil have unintended side-effects.

A possible solution for you might be to have a long running process performing your tasks which gets a wake-up signal from a light cron process.

Another possibility would be build something using [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/), which is much lighter than AMQP style queues (at the cost of some features of course). Tarek Ziade is working on a Mozilla project called [powerhose](https://github.com/mozilla-services/powerhose) that uses 0mq, looks super simple, and has a heartbeat capability with resolution to the second.

Comment: Here is Tarek's reasoning for building this library: http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/scaling-crypto-work-in-python/

Comment: Aha. Regarding that comment, I understand the problem of lifecycle management well enough (also, as far as I understand, if only django's internal web server is used that won't be too much of a problem).  But what exactly goes on with temporary threads and can't it be fixed?