# django code which runs event independent

Tags: python, django, web-applications, backend

I am creating a web application in django and I want to create a backend app which runs continuously instead of running only when the "view" is called. How do I do this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org). It is a task queue that tightly integrates with Django.

You can also create a custom management command that contains a `while True: ... sleep` loop.

In any case, you should set `DEBUG` to false, otherwise [Django will eat up your memory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory).

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/

This is a plugin, which will allow you to put some tasks for independent execution.

Also this question contains good solution for this question: [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: I tried it after you posted and i found celery better ! Thanks btw !

Answer (score 0):

Django is not especially for this; that said, you can use django's facilities, and just write a programme that executes continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Write a management command and daemonize it with supervisord.

By the way, technically django itself is running continuously and not only when view is called.

What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Create a Compiler Judge backend that periodically checks for new solutions and compiles them.