# How to schedule task in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-signals, django-settings

What is the best way to Schedule job in Django. My aim is to send balance statement PDF email to the user as per their independent setting (like daily, Weekly, monthly). 
How do the checking should be done? Please do advise i am a newbie in Django and python world.
I am using WindowsXP, python 2.7.2, Django 1.3.1 and MS-SQL2008 Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

You can also find some nice examples on [Celery wiki page](https://github.com/ask/celery/wiki/) such as [django-celery-email](https://bitbucket.org/pmclanahan/django-celery-email).

Comment: Exactly, celery + rabbitmq is all you want

Comment: django celery link broken, it's on github now [link](https://github.com/pmclanahan/django-celery-email)