# Best way to schedule task in Django, without Celery

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

Im looking for relatively simple and lightweight way to setup primitive DB maintain tasks for Django-based web-site. Celery seems for me like overkill.
In my mind its now looking like making custom Django management command, and putting in in cron. 
Maybe some could suggest better method?

Comment: If you need something lightweight, management command could be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

[django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) has a [jobs-scheduling function](http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/jobs_scheduling.html) that would work well for DB maintenance tasks. You still would rely on cron entries to actually run them though.

But then again, just doing a management command from cron is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

[Django Chronograph](https://bitbucket.org/wnielson/django-chronograph) is a django app with a very nice admin interface for managing Cron Jobs and setting up multiple task. So in this way, you don't have to go and fiddle with your server's cron file and this interface/app would manage it efficiently for you.

You can also do it the Django way by writing [Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) as also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job).