# Django setting up a scheduled task without Cron

Tags: django, task, schedule

I know there are many questions asking about this, especially this one: [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job).

But what I want to understand is, how does a scheduled task inside Django actually works?

My simplistic way to think about it is that there's an infinite loop somewhere, something like this (runs every 60 seconds),

```
import time
interval=60  #60 seconds 
while True:
    some_method()
    time.sleep(interval)
```

Question: where do you put this infinite loop? Is there some part of the Django app that just runs in the background alongside the rest of the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't do scheduled tasks.  If you want scheduled tasks, you need a daemon that runs all the time and can launch your task at the appropriate time.

Django only runs when a http request is made.  If no one makes a http request for a month, django doesn't run for a month.  If there are 45 http requests this second, django will run 45 times this second (in the absence of caching).

You can write scripts in the django framework (called management commands) that get called from some outside service (like cron).  That's as close as you'll get to what you want.  If that's the case, then the question/answer you reference is the place to get the how tos.

Probably on a unixy system, cron is the simplest outside service to work with.  On recent linux systems, cron has a directory /etc/cron.d into which you can drop your app's cron config file, and it will not interfere with any other cron jobs on the system.  No editing of existing files necessary.