# Django execute task on time specified in model datetime field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-celery

got a simple question, I believe, but it got me stuck anyways.

Say I have a simple model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    expires = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

and I want, say on the specified time do something: send an email, delete model, change some of the models fields... Something. Is there a tool in django core, allowing me to do so?

Or, if not, I think some task queuing tool might be in order. I have `djcelery` working in my project, though I'm a completely newbie in it, and all I was able to perform so far, is to run `django-celery-email` package, in order to send my mail asynchronically. Though I can't say I'm fully capable of defining task and workers to work in background and be reliable.

If any ideas, on how to solve such problem, please, do not hesitate =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is a background-task the reads the datime and executes a task if a datetime is or has been reached.

See the solution given here for a [scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

So the workflow would be:

- Create the task you want to apply on objects whose date has been reached
- Create a managment command that checks the datetimes in your DB, and execute the above task for every object the datetime has been reached
- Use cron (Linux) or at(Windows) to schedule the command call

Answer (score 4):

1. Write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) to do the task that you desire. When you are done, you should be able to run your task with `python manage.py yourtaskname`.
2. Use `cron`, `at`, [periodic tasks in `celery`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), [`django-cron`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron), [`djangotaskscheduler`](http://code.google.com/p/djangotaskscheduler/) or [`django-future`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-future/0.2.1) to schedule your tasks.

Answer (score -2):

If you're on a UNIX-like machine, it's possible that you have access to [cronjobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). If you're on Windows, I hear there's a program called `at` that can do similar things. If this doesn't suit your needs, there are a number of ways to do things every X hours using the `time` library (`time.sleep(SOME_NUMBER_OF_SECONDS)` in a loop with whatever else you want to do will do it if you want something done regularly, otherwise you'll need to look at `time.localtime()` and check for conditions).