# DJANGO Dynamically Create A Task to run Views

Tags: django, task

I am a NewBee. I have a personal website which parses data from other online websites to show users specific data which they have opted for.
What I want is to run one of my django views script which automatically should run every day at midnight.
The webpage view which I want to run asks user their name to be searched and the results are shown on screen as well as emailed to them. To do this every user has to click search button on the webpage. I want to automate this.
I want this process to happen every day automatically and run for each user's name saved in the database.
I have no clue how to go about it.
I have seen these django-scheduler etc but couldnot understand a think how to go about.
Can someone please help me.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

Comment: Also, this sounds like the job of a management command, and not a view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job