# Automatically update database in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a website that displays stock information and I have a file called populate_stocks.py that populates the database with a given set of stocks. Since these stocks change almost every minute, I need to make sure I update the database with new information by running populate_stocks.py again.

I was wondering if there is any way to let my django application automatically call this file to update the stock information. I searched around and found another person using crontab which seems a bit complicated and was wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: Crontab is complicated? :D Dude... that's the simpliest thing you'll ever see when it comes to scheduling tasks.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Comment: yeah cron is the easy way. the more complex way involves setting up Celery to run tasks, which from what i know, is quite complex.

Comment: I see that by modifying the crontab file, you can automatically update the information on your computer. But to do this you would have to hard-code computer specific information in file. Since I am planning to deploy my website using python anywhere, I wanted to do it in such a way to avoid computer specific information.

Comment: @user2548635 what do you mean update the information on your computer? Cronjobs are just timed tasks....

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree that the use of crontab to solve this problem is actually probably the easiest solution to this problem, there is a possible alternative over crontab which would be to make a management function that runs alongside your server.

Basically in its absolute simplest form you would make a basic loop in the form of a Django NoArgsCommand.

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from populate_stocks import yourmysticalfunctionofupdating

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
   help = "This runs the loop of glory, that does as it is told."

   def handle_noargs(self, **options):
      while True:
         yourmysticalfunctionofupdating()
```

You would need to put this into a management -> commands folder and name the python file whatever you want the command should be (imagine it is updatify.py in this example).

You could then run the following command to run your watchdog.

```
./manage.py updatify
```

Though this may be overkill for your particular problem I have found it very helpful for trickier issues, and I hope it saves someone some time.