# How to perform a specific task in django automatically after a fixed interval of time?

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-applications, automation

Lets say I have a database model in Django which stores top 100 songs. This data comes from an api.

The problem is that the song ranking may change from time to time [30 minutes/ 1 hour].

I wish to implement a method in the web app such that it automatically runs a particular function in python [ which updates the database by sending api requests] every 10 minutes , whether there is a user online or not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Celery for this, but it is probably overkill if you just have simple task.
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create a django management task wich update the song raking and call it with a cron every ten minutes.

related answere : [django scheduled job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)