# Add cron job in django based on admin settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, scripting, cron

I am using python 2.7 with django 1.8.
I have the admin panel ready and working.

What I want is to run a (python) script every 5-10 minutes (cron?) which pulls the data from records specified by the admin.
Any pointers how do I proceed?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "from records specified by the admin"

Comment: @coldmind, my database has two fields and multiple records. The admin will select any two records and I need to compute the logical 'AND' value of the second field those records.
I need to do this for all the combinations selected by the admin. And I need to keep repeating this every 5 mins.

Question 1: Where should I write my logic to do this? (I'm using Django)
Question 2: How to automate this to run every 5 secs?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question, I think you have the same goals.

[Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

Hope it helps!