# Have Django periodically refresh data

Tags: python, django, sqlite, middleware

I am doing some tasks with tens of thousands of activity directory objects that can take several minutes to load.

To speed up things up I'd like to just refresh this data into the sqllite database in the middle of the night (since there's no need for it to be current).

Is there a way to typically approach to this type of problem? Perhaps have Django periodically run a function somehow?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a [django admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) and use **cron** or **at** to execute the command.

or just use a django cron lib:

- [django-cron](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron)
- [django-crontab](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab)

Comment: Thanks I think I will give it a try.