# django - clear data in table every day at certain time

Tags: django, multithreading, postgresql, process

I have my server side in django with postgres.

What I want to do is to clear a specific table from all of its data at 12:00 (midnight) everyday.

I guess the code for delete will be

```
Rides.objects.all().delete()
```

What I am not sure about is how to have a **process** or sort of a  **thread** that will do it everyday at 12:00.

Also I think maybe the server clock should be set to my TimeZone, to make sure its deleting the data at 12:00 exactly.

How should I go about this? any ideas?

Comment: Its done via the so called [cron jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: "server clock should be set to my TimeZone", the time zone you're in isn't always the same, it shouldn't be hard to figure out what your idea of 12:00 on the server is

Answer (score 0):

Create management command

Create a file inside the app directory

> management/commands/cleanup_rides.py

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from models import Ride

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = "cleaning up rides"

    def handle_noargs(self, **options):
        Ride.objects.all().delete()
```

then add it to the crontab run the command `crontab -e` add the below line

> 0 0 * * * path/to/python path/to/project/manage.py cleanup_rides

the managment command runs every day midnight and delete all the records in ride table.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did all the above, but when trying to run the command in  the project class - I get error: 'crontab' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I guess I need to install something? working in windows  8

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you are working in linux. The windows equivalent to a cron job is a scheduled task.

Comment: Thanks.  Eventually I will have this django server running in heroku,  I should be able to use crontab with heroku right?