# Best way to trigger a function when DateField in model expires

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a "Contest" model that a user creates and one of the fields is

`(endTime = models.DateField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=7))`.

I need a method to run a function when their contest has expired. The function would be to notify users, update objects, etc.

What would be the best method to achieve this?

Comment: You just want to notify the creator that their contest has expired? Do you want to send them an email or just a notification when they are on your site?

Comment: Well there will be a big chunk of code that will need to be ran that will update many objects. Basically just looking for the best procedure to identify that the datetime field has passed.

Comment: And this can't be based on a user logging in or any user behaviour. This has to run in the background somehow.

Comment: For example, how do sites like eBay run all of the "ending auction" code when the auction ends? Schedule a task everytime auction is created I suppose. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule a task you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

as for a this question,

> procedure to identify that the datetime field has passed

This would work:

```
Contest.objects.filter(endTime__lte=timezone.now())
```

So you would have a task running continuously that would call a django command every *X* hours, that would use the above search to find any expired contests.

Comment: That method would work for scheduling it based on a predetermined date rather than a DateField for each particular "contest". Not looking to "schedule" a task, looking for a task to run based on a "DateField".

Comment: I suppose you could schedule a task everytime a contest is created...hmm.

Comment: You would have a task that runs continuously in the background, that would call a django command that searches the database using: `Contest.objects.filter(endTime__lte=timezone.now())` and it would call this command every _X_ hours.

Comment: Do you think the continuous task in the background would be superior to scheduling a task everytime a contest is created?

Comment: That's a separate question, but in short, yes that would be better.

Comment: The main question is the best way to do this! But ok thanks!