# Django run view automatically every day

Tags: django, email, timer, view

On my website I have a system of liking and uliking models. I want to make view, that checks every users number of likes received. If the number of likes exeeds 5, than the django should send email to the user, saying that he has more than 5 likes. How could I i make this work? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Python package celery with a beat scheduler. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html