# how to implement fortnightly email notification in Django

Tags: python, django, email, notifications

I am relatively new to Django. I would like to send email notification fortnightly to the intended user. How do i do tat ? For example, user will enter their start date. Then i have to figure out the start date and make my app send notification FORTNIGHTLY from the start date until i stop this task. So which means the sending notification will vary according to the start date the users have entered.

Comment: You have many tools available to schedule tasks. You can use celery, cron job...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Answer (score 1):

[Use periodic tasks with celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) that is the best option for send email notification.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour='6'))
```

This will run the function every day on 6:00 AM
For more details of schedules Refer http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

Comment: but will this be doing the fortnight thing ? cause i have to implement notification on sending email fortnightly

Comment: @Mandy Yes there are many settings of periodic_task

Comment: There is no explicit way of setting cron job to be fortnightly, it only has knowledge of days of the week/ days of the month. You can however test for odd/even weeks of the year in function body.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use your OS scheduler (like cron on unices) to execute a custom [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/). You'll have to implement a way to store which users should get which mails so the management command can work it out. This works fine for the simplest cases but can become a mess very quickly...

The more complex solution is to use some async queue system (Celery is the usual culprit but there are alternatives).