# Send Reminder Email using Django

Tags: django, reminders, django-email

I have a model of student with event date time and student's email field.
I want to send a reminder email 12hours before event time to student's email. What are the ways to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to schedule email reports to users in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443358/best-way-to-schedule-email-reports-to-users-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a scheduler for this. Celery is one of the most popular tools used for such tasks with Django.

With celery, you can set a certain task to run at a given time like so:

```
send_reminder_email.apply_async(eta=datetime_object)
```

You can read more details here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html