# How schedule a job (Django, Python)

Tags: python, django, runtime, schedule

I would like to create a job that rolls to all 10 munites.
I find a good example [here](http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/). The problem is that the program is freezing during the waiting time and my other urls are blocked.
after me it's because of ***while True:***

Is there a way to do it without going around this problem?

**voici le code:**

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

*******************************************************************.

I found the right way to do it. Here is the [link](http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/):
For that to work well, I removed this part:

```
# time.sleep(20)
# print('Checkpoint **************************')
# time.sleep(30)
# print('Bye -----------------------')
```

Here is the code that works:

```
import threading
class ThreadingExample(object):
    """ Threading example class
    The run() method will be started and it will run in the background
    until the application exits.
    """

    def __init__(self, interval=10):
        """ Constructor
        :type interval: int
        :param interval: Check interval, in seconds
        """
        self.interval = interval

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True                            # Daemonize thread
        thread.start()                                  # Start the execution

    def run(self):
        """ Method that runs forever """
        while True:
            # Do something
            print('Doing something imporant in the background', self.interval)
            pk_info_semaine = job_temp.objects.all()
            for a in pk_info_semaine:
                print('num_semaine:',a.num_semaine,'user_id:',a.user_id)
            time.sleep(self.interval)

example = ThreadingExample()
```

Thank you all and thank you to the author: Paris Nakita Kejser [Here](https://github.com/parisnakitakejser)

Comment: Maybe the [schedule FAQ](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-continuously-run-the-scheduler-without-blocking-the-main-thread) can help you

Comment: Depending on what you are doing you might want to look at other frameworks that were built with django in mind for doing scheduled tasks... It doesn't look like `schedule` is one of them

Comment: The answers in this question are good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job

Answer (score 3):

You can use celery + celerybeat together with Django to run scheduled tasks. You can write your method as a celery task, and add an entry in your **settings.py** file to make the task run every 10 minutes. The task will run in its on thread, hence not blocking your application.

**voici le link to celery:**
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Thank you, I will follow the instructions.
I will get back to you on the final result.