# How can I create object day by day in Django?

Tags: python, django, date, time

I have just begin the Django web framework and I am trying to make internship diary application. I want to create an model which has name as "RecordedWorkDay" automatically for each intern user. But these object should be created by program for each day. What I mean is if today is Monday, tomorrow new object should be created by program.

```
#That is my user class which extends from AbstractUser

class CustomizedUser(AbstractUser):
    authory_choices = (
        ("İntern", "İntern"),
        ("Manager", "Manager"),
    )
    authory = models.CharField(choices=authory_choices, default="İntern", max_length=10)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def is_intern(self):
        if self.authory == "İntern":
            return True
        return False

    def is_manager(self):
        if self.authory == "Manager":
            return True
        return False


    #This class should save diary text for each day
    class RecordedWorkDays(models.Model):
        # TextField that holds users' working day records
        record = models.TextField()
        #Corresponding intern that owns this day object
        assignedIntern = models.ForeignKey(CustomizedUser, related_name="assigned", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look in the django docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/