# Is there a better way to schedule a task with Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cron

I have made a Django project and I would like to run several scripts automatically, some of them every minutes other every hour ...

My first thoughts were to make a custom Django command and create a crontab.
 
[Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job?rq=1)
Like this.
I'm looking for if there is a better way in 2019 to made it or eventually if Django framework implemented this functionnality.

My project work with docker (Image : Python / OS :Ubuntu).

Thanks

Comment: You should look at [`celery`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: What's wrong with cron jobs?