# Django scheduler with aws-lambda

Tags: python, django, web-applications, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks

I have Django Postgres Database with DateField which is date of sending some message (SMS and email). I would like to schedule delivering somehow (so basically run function with parameters at this date). Everything is running on aws-lambda. 
I read [Django - Set Up A Scheduled Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/django-set-up-a-scheduled-job) but I wondering if there isn't some strictly aws solution. Or maybe if there is something better than https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have used aws cloudwatch which runs lambda which pings my django endpoint every [n] minutes.