# Filter a model by date range of next week in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I filter the model data according to date range of two columns - `birthday` and `anniversary` which are `datefield`s using Django querysets?
This is in a function that is called every friday. So the date range will be from tomorrow i.e., Saturday to next Friday.

```
def mailer_function():
    model_data = Model.objects.filter(
                  birthday__range=["tomorrow(i.e., Saturday's date)", "next friday's date"],
                  anniversary__range=["tomorrow(i.e., Saturday's date)", "next friday's date"]
                 )
```

Here I should get the model_data whose birthday or anniversary dates are in the next week.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a scheduled job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: Yes but only the first part. It does not answer how to filter for the next week using django querysets.

Comment: You did 0 work researching answers to your question and want someone else to solve it for you. There dozens of duplicates of your questions already answered on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```
import datetime

def next_week():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    return [
        today + datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    ]
```

And if you want to filter birthday OR anniversary, check [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q

queryset = Model.objects.filter(
    Q(birthday__range=next_week()) | Q(anniversary__range=next_week())
)
```

To schedule use your favorite external tool, something like cron. I suggest to create your task as a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the program on a scheduled basis using an external program like anacron.

I would suggest to use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) for this as it keeps all your scheduled tasks internal to your project.

Comment: Ok. That will solve the first part. How can I filter for the next week starting from saturday to next friday?