# Cyclical operations in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my frontend application I have a panel which shows 6 the most popular products on my site. Searching for the most popular products each request by the number of views can be costly. I think that a good way to improve it will be to create a table in my data base which will store 6 the most popular products and the table will be refreshed for example every one minute. What should I looking for to do so cyclical operation on my django backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a scheduled job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: Why not write an ajax request that update the top 6 product that you can save in the session

Comment: you want to run a operation in perticular period so  you use django cron for this cron is used to run perticular operation in fixed period  here you will find how to use it https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate model

#### models.py

```py
class ProductRecord(models.Model):

    product = models.OneToOneField(
        'Product'
        related_name='stats', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Data used for generating a score
    num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    num_basket_additions = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0)
    num_purchases = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0)

    # Product score - used within search
    score = models.FloatField(default=0.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return _("Record for '%s'") % self.product
```

#### rule_engine.py

```py
class Calculator:
    weights = {
        'num_views': 1,
        'num_basket_additions': 3,
        'num_purchases': 5
    }

    def calculate_scores(self):
        total_weight = float(sum(self.weights.values()))
        weighted_fields = [
            self.weights[name] * F(name) for name in self.weights.keys()]
        ProductRecord.objects.update(
            score=sum(weighted_fields) / total_weight)
```

#### receivers.py

Here you'll have multiple signals to receive addition to basket, views, favoriting, and so on..

This is an example

```py
def receive_product_view(sender, product, user, **kwargs):
   UserProductView.objects.create(product=product, user=user)
   ## yyou can do much advanced staff here using signals
```

### Another solution

You can use **Redis** to save such these data like counts and purchases
Or make **aws lambda** function for receiving analytical data, all of these solutions depend on your case

This is a pseudo solution. hope it's been beneficial to you

Comment: Thank You for help! I'll check it.