# How to schedule the custom management command in Django on windows?

Tags: django

I need to schedule the custom management django command. I am using windows. I tried django-crontab but that's not working.
Can someone please help me with this?

In my_app here is the file "check_links" :

[image]

check_links.py

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Check broken links'
    
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print("function executed")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a scheduled job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: It has useful information. I already tried crontab but it has no support for windows. But I need some way to schedule custom command on windows.