# How to create automated script which deletes php session files on linux server?

Tags: php

I have a problem with accumulating sessions (codeigniter) in /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74

I use this command rm -rf ea-php74 to remove sessions manually

Sessions have a strange naming so default PHP session cleaner is not working __g4cw44g840000kk8gw4848k8804ww8o08gc8s80w2

How to create an automated command that would run that command every day or every two days?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a scheduled job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573618/set-up-a-scheduled-job)

Comment: Do you need it for cPanel website or whole server?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your server.  If it's a Linux server you would want to use CRON.

https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/advanced/cron-jobs/

Comment: Aren't crons in cpanel jobs confined to execute just what is in that user's home folder?